# Issue with 100vw including scrollbar width

Tags: css, scrollbar, viewport-units

I have a div that needs to be full screen width inside a parent div that has a limited with. Simplified, it's something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}
.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc( 50% - 50vw);
}
```

which works fine, except for one thing: The scrollbar on the page covers some of the content in the child div, because 100vw appearantly includes the scrollbar width. So is there a way around this so I can set the width to (100vw - scrollbar width), or perhaps a completely different way to achieve what I want to do with pure CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655759/vertical-scrollbar-appears-when-width-is-larger-than-100vw/51656038#51656038

Comment: can you describe what you want to achieve? you want to make the banner overflowing ?

Comment: Why are you using vw at all, instead of percentage?

Comment: Just put `overflow-x:hidden` on the body?

Comment: @Temani Afif – Yes, I want the banner to overflow, making it full screen width.

Comment: @paddyfields – because it's inside a limited width container. 100% width just makes it same width as its parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D –  overflow-x:hidden on body doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the scrollbar width and subtract it from the container's width using 'pure CSS'.

You could give width to the scroll bar in webkit-browsers using:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: scrollbarwidthpx;
}
```

and set the content width as:

```
width: calc(100vw - scrollbarwidthpx);
```

[You could make use of this article regarding customizing scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use % where you can. vw is a percent of the viewport width including the scrollbar while % is a percent of the wrapper object which does not get confused by the scrollbar.

In general:

- Don't use a fixed width (px) container. It's bad practice and will not render well on mobile screens. See Responsive Web Design for more.
- Don't use vw for containers (or banners). It has weird effects on the scrollbar.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way... The op did not ask for general tips...

Comment: @zeraien "or perhaps a completely different way to achieve what I want to do with pure CSS" - OP. "% is a percent of the wrapper object, where the body is not rendered inside the scrollbar"

I'll make it more clear that "%" solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Well if your banner is just image you can use, this CSS.

First you should delete this

```
.container { width: 1170px; margin: auto; }
```

Change to this

```
.container {
    display: block;
}
```

Then add this

```
.container div.banner { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url('yourbanner.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).